# SingleChildScrollView overflows instead of scrolls

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Why does this `SingleChildScrollView` overflow instead of scroll when the screen height is resized too small? I've used this design because the bottom widget needs to be pushed to the bottom.

```
return NavigationListener(builder: (context, child) {
  return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: SizedBox(
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
    width: maxSideMenuWidth,
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Container(
            height: 155, color: Colors.purple, child: const MenuHeader()),
        Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            height: 327,
            child: MainMenu(
              primaryDestinations: primaryDestinations,
              secondaryDestinations: secondaryDestinations,
              onNavigate: onNavigate,
              isSelected: isSelected,
            )),
        Spacer(),
        Container(
            color: Colors.green,
            height: 135,
            child: LoginContextWidget(user, userDetails, logOut)),
      ],
    ),
  ));
});
```

Comment: It can be that a child `Container`'s child is overflowing.

Comment: try wrapping column with singlechildscrollview

Comment: can you prove and image that will indicate the heights of `LoginContextWidget` , `MenuHeader` and  `MainMenu`.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This code**

```
return NavigationListener(builder: (context, child) {
  return SizedBox(
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
    width: maxSideMenuWidth,
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
      children: [
        Container(
            height: 155, color: Colors.purple, child: const MenuHeader()),
        Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            height: 327,
            child: MainMenu(
              primaryDestinations: primaryDestinations,
              secondaryDestinations: secondaryDestinations,
              onNavigate: onNavigate,
              isSelected: isSelected,
            )),
        Spacer(),
        Container(
            color: Colors.green,
            height: 135,
            child: LoginContextWidget(user, userDetails, logOut)),
      ],
    ),
    ),
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap singlechildscrollview in expanded

```
return NavigationListener(builder: (context, child) {
 return Expanded(
   child:SingleChildScrollView(
   child: SizedBox(
   height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
   width: maxSideMenuWidth,

child: Column(
  children: [
    Container(
        height: 155, color: Colors.purple, child: const MenuHeader()),
    Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        height: 327,
        child: MainMenu(
          primaryDestinations: primaryDestinations,
          secondaryDestinations: secondaryDestinations,
          onNavigate: onNavigate,
          isSelected: isSelected,
        )),
    Spacer(),
    Container(
        color: Colors.green,
        height: 135,
        child: LoginContextWidget(user, userDetails, logOut)),
      ],
    ),
  ));
  };
});
```